# Get rid of 0s before running chi-square test

Tags: r, chi-squared

My variable `RaceCat` looks like this after coding `table(data$RaceCat)`

[image]

I want to run a chi-square test but I know I need to get rid of the races American Indian and Middle Eastern since those have 0s. `American Indian` is coded as 5 and `Middle Eastern` is 4. My thought process is to do `data%>% filter(RaceCat!=5)%>% filter(RaceCat!=4)`
However, when I try to do that, R says `length of 'dimnames' [2] not equal to array extent`.

Here is another thing I tried to do:

```
hivneg<-droplevels(hivneg)
a<- table(hivneg$RaceCat, hivneg$PrEP2)
chisq.test(a, correct=F)
```

However, the `table()` and `chisq.test()` won't run. It says

> Warning message in mapply(FUN = f, ..., SIMPLIFY = FALSE):
> “longer argument not a multiple of length of shorter”

Comment: Is this race variable part of your expected or your observed? If it's part of your observed, you don't need to drop it. Chi-square is well-defined for zero-value observed counts.

Answer (score 1):

From the image showed, it seems that the column 'RaceCat' is `factor` `class` with some unused `levels`.  An option is to update the data with `droplevels` which removes those unused levels in any of the `factor` columns

```
data <- droplevels(data)
```

NOTE: `table` just returns the frequency count of each of the unique values/ or if it is a `factor`, the count of each of the `levels` of the `factor`.

Comment: I tried that but it didn't seem to work. I did hivneg<-droplevels(hivneg)

a<- table(hivneg$RaceCat, hivneg$PrEP2)
chisq.test(a, correct=F) but I got the warning "longer argument not a multiple of length of shorter”

Comment: @user16914149 when you say it didn't work, what you are getting as output.  - error or warning or anyting else

Comment: my output says Warning message in mapply(FUN = f, ..., SIMPLIFY = FALSE):
“longer argument not a multiple of length of shorter”

Comment: @user16914149 can you update your post with the `dput(a)`

Comment: @user16914149 your description in the post suggest that you are creating `a` from just a single column 'RaceCat'

Comment: how would I recode this?

Comment: @user16914149 if you can show the `dput(a)`, can test it

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand how to use dput

Comment: @user16914149 just `dput(a)` and copy/paste the output from the console i.e  the structure of your data